# Check if Android device has an internal speaker

Tags: android

How to check if a device running Android has a speaker on it or not? Meaning is it able to play audio?

Are there any Configuration qualifiers for it? and what about programmatically

EDIT: just bought an Android Wear watch and it does NOT have a speaker so not sure how I would check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android API doesn't have any such qualifiers neither there is any library method.

But just a raw idea, try playing some audio and simultaneously record through the mic.
Check if they are same.
This is not a fool proof way, but just a thought!

Comment: Not sure about the "Try playing some audio and simultaneously record through the mic" but points awarded for the "there is no way to check this"

Answer (score 3):

Since API level 21 (most Android Wear based on this level), Android provide a feature, [`PackageManager.FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT), witch can be used to detect whether there is a way to output the audio.

I tested this feature on my MOTO 360 (no speaker), it don't has this feature, and Ticwatch (with speaker) do have this feature.

But when I connected a Bluetooth headset to the MOTO 360, it still don't have this feature, this confused me.

So I use [`AudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isBluetoothA2dpOn()) for further check.

The detection code can be like this:

```
public boolean hasAudioOutput() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    if (audioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()) {
        // Adjust output for Bluetooth.
        return true;
    } else if (audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()) {
        // Adjust output for Bluetooth of sco.
        return true;
    } else if (audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
        // Adjust output for headsets
        return true;
    } else if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
        // Adjust output for Speakerphone.
        return true;
    } else if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT)) {
        // Has internal speaker or other form of audio output.
        return true;
    } else {
        // No device for audio output.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably most android phones have a speaker i guess :P /.. But if you are asking if you can check whether its connected to a speaker or headphones or something like that..then you can use

```
if (isBluetoothA2dpOn()) {
    // Adjust output for Bluetooth.
} else if (isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
    // Adjust output for Speakerphone.
} else if (isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
    // Adjust output for headsets
} else { 
    // If audio plays and noone can hear it, is it still playing?
}
```

SOURCE: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html#CheckHardware

Comment: Well I just bought an Android Wear watch and it does NOT have audio so hmmm...not quite sure if this is what I'm looking for

Comment: AH i see..Is there any specific reason that you need to check for audio(Cause you cant hear it anyway even if its played)...

Comment: Which company?? beacuse Android wear watches do NOT have a speaker. They have an audio jack instead

Comment: @TusharGupta well yes the 2 watches available do not have a speaker. However in the future some might. Also trying to use the majority of the same code base for wear and mobile so if I had a solution that detected a speaker or not that would be nice

Comment: Hey there..U know you can use the post above to do what you want..use the last else to handle it,..for example if speaker and headset are not on,then it goes to the  final else..this probably checks if audio is playing and no one is hearing it..I dont have a android watch to check it out..but it does work when i try it on muted devices