# Android: Determine number of speakers used for AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, audiotrack, speaker, hal

I have attempted to find any info regarding the detection of the number of speakers available. When the AudioTrack streaming mode is set to music (allowing the phone's loud speakers to be used) I would like to detect if the sound will be coming from multiple speakers or only one.

Comment: You can't : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24781310/4491275